# Asterisk in sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql script in which we specify path of the .csv data file contains data to be loaded in database.

The name of the data file may change so I need to generalize the script.Basically data file may contain version number which may change over time.

For example:

```
BULK INSERT tablename
FROM 'C:\Data\abc_1_123.csv'
```

Is there a way I can specify file location like

```
BULK INSERT tablename
FROM 'C:\Data\abc_*.csv'
```

which would generalize the script.

Comment: have you tried `%` instead of `*`? That's often used as the wildcard character in SQL Server

Comment: you can save csv file path in sql variable and excute dynamic sql

Comment: Can you please show an example of executing above task in dynamic sql. Basically C:\Data\abc_*.csv would return just one file. Can I do something like this. @filename = 'C:\Data\abc_*.csv'; BULK INSERT tablename
FROM '''+@filename+'''